# Variable on JOption Displayed 2 times

Tags: java, joptionpane

I want to display the variable toPay at the last part.

Example I entered 0 to variable toPay and after that it going to call the main(args) again and then Im going to enter 4 but the output is

JOption "To Pay: 28" which is correct but after i close the JOptionpane something popups again and it says JOption "To Pay 0"

```
package Payphone;

import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Try {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int toPay=0;

    int n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter calltime"));
    if (n<=0) {
        toPay = 0;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error!");
    Try.main(args);

    }else if (n<=3){
        toPay =20;
    }else{
       toPay =n - 3;
       toPay =(toPay*3)+20;
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Babayadan mo: "+toPay,"PAYCHECK",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}
}
```

Comment: do you want to run this program continuously as long as you input `0` ?

Answer (score 1):

This error is happening because you are calling your program AGAIN at this point `Try.main(args);` so when an error occur you set `toPay = 0;`, then you show the error message, but your last line calls the JOptionPane again, so after executing the first JOptionPane correctly, the program will still execute the last JOptionPane and will show you "Babayadan mo: 0".

To correct this situation you have to end your program or do something like this:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Try {

    private static int n;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        babayadan();
    }

    public static void restart() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error!");
        n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter calltime"));
    }

    public static void babayadan() {
        n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter calltime"));

        while(n <= 0) {
            restart();
        }

        int toPay = 0;
        if (n <= 3){
            toPay = 20;
        }else {
            toPay = n - 3;
            toPay =(toPay * 3) + 20;
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Babayadan mo: " + toPay, "PAYCHECK", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```